# Dual of the alternative solutions

Tags: linear-programming, duality, dual

Suppose we have two alternative solutions for a linear program. Are their corresponding dual solutions the same? (in terms of the values for each dual variable)

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1641575/175986)'s an example of a primal-dual pair with multiple solutions.